# How to compare Objects values which is inside two different list in Java?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have two Lists, say `listA` and `listA1`, `listA` contains object of class `A` type and `listA1` also contains object of type class `A`.But `listA` added class `A` objects by java code and listA1 adds class A objects by converting `JSON` String to Class `A`.

Now I need to compare `listA` and `listA1`. If `listA` contains any objects which also are in `listA1` I need to remove that object and return back `listA` with all the objects which are not in `listA1`.

How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: @zander I used contains() method which is working fine when objects are same its not comparing values..

Comment: First of all Class A must have a "valid" equals implementation, then we can use [List.removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: Implement a custom(your own) equals method for class A and use this method to compare and remove the objects using the method suggested by @white

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java, implement equals and hashCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement(override) `equals` method as below on your class `A`. Once done, `contains` method should help.

```
  public boolean equals(A a){
       boolean bEqual = false;
       if(this.value1!= null && a.value1!= null && 
          this.value1.eqauls(a.value1)
          ........
          ........
        ) {
          bEqual = true;              
        }
        return bEqual;
   }
```

**EDIT:**

Iterate elements of `listA1`. If they are present in `listA`, remove them.

```
   for(A a: listA1){
     if(listA.contains(a)){
        listA.remove(a);
     }
   }
```

Comment: listA contains 15 element(Class A's object) and listA1 contains  5 elements(Class A's object) now i have to compare values of objects(listA and listA1) and remove all the objects from listA and which are also present in listA1.Thanks

Comment: Thanks Yogendra i am doing same
for (A : listA) {

   if (listA.contains(A)) {
    listA.remove(value);
   }
  }
but that not working may be the addres of objects are diffrent because contains not checking values its checking address of object .its my thinking

Comment: If it works for you, please don't forget to accept to close this question thread.

Comment: Did you implement the equals method (comparing field values) in your class `A`?

Comment: Please share you class `A` attributes with their data type. I will help you implement the `equals` method.

Comment: Thanks i used your solution and i posted what exact code i did .

Answer (score 0):

Apache's commons.collections library has a CollectionUtils class that provides easy-to-use methods for Collection manipulation/checking, such as intersection, difference, and union.

[The org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils API](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) docs are here.

I think, You can use intersaction methos for that

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to compare two objects, then see the [comparing objects](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Comparing_Objects)

also, How it works [equals](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

What exact thing i did to resolve the issue.....

```
 public static class A  {


        String  headerName;

        public String getHeaderName() {
            return headerName;
        }
        public void setListBoxHeaderName(String headerName) {
            this.headerName= headerName;
        }
        public A(String headerName) {
            super();

            this.headerName = headerName;
        }


        public boolean equals(A rData) {
            boolean bEqual = false;
            if (this.getHeaderName() != null && rData.getHeaderName() != null
                    && this.getHeaderName().equals(rData.getHeaderName())) {
                bEqual = true;
            }
            return bEqual;
        }

    }
```

And for comparing two list the code is as follows...

```
for (A value1 : listA1) {
            for (A value2: listA) {
                if (value2.equals(value1 )) {
                 listA.remove(value2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what the exact solution i used Thanks